# 2 dimensional array sorting by input then second

Tags: java

It's probably a rather basic question but I can't seem to find an answer that I require online.

However, what's the best way to sort a 2 dimensional array?

I have a pre-populated 2 dimensional array 'mainArr[][]' that contains data:

```
John Doe - 678DGHJ,Sport
Lisa Parker - 432KH3,Car
John Doe - 678DGHJ, Drive
Peter Bear 4HJ4K3,Bus
John Doe - 4HJK4,Loose
```

The comma being the separator between the dimension in the array. 
How can I sort it first by the column first in the array, then by the value in the second part of the array.

The sorted data above would become:

```
John Doe - 4HJK4,Loose
John Doe - 678DGHJ,Drive
John Doe - 678DGHJ,Sport
Lisa Parker - 432KH3,Car
Peter Bear 4HJ4K3,Bus
```

So the sorted data in the array of

```
mainArr[0][0]
```

would equal

```
mainArr[John Doe - 4HJK4][Loose]
```

Comment: I'm not clear, is the list you have mentioned is the intended outcome or the one you have currently got?

Comment: The first is the data that I have, and the list below it is the outcome that I want.

Comment: You should rethink your design. Why are you storing things in a 2D array when you can create an object with appropriate fields that can be accessed and sorted with `Collections.sort()` with very little additional programming on your part?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that for this part it would be better. However, for the next part I require it to be in a 2 dimensional array, sadly.

Comment: looks like a homework question.

Comment: No it's not. It's for my job

Comment: The tail shouldn't wag the dog... can you explain the rationale behind this 2D array approach? What I'm getting at is that you might think that you're wedded to this terribad approach when you could very well be able to free yourself. The alternative is to do your own implementation of a merge sort and resolve equal strings with the contents of the second array (you'd only ever care about the second array in the case of a tie). The trick is to retain the index of the value being evaluated so that it can be used to retrieve the corresponding second value if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Comparator` like below to sort your array,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[][] mainArr = new String[][] {{"John Doe - 678DGHJ", "Sport"}, {"Lisa Parker - 432KH3", "Car"}, {"John Doe - 678DGHJ", "Drive"}, {"Peter Bear 4HJ4K3", "Bus"}, {"John Doe - 4HJK4", "Loose"}};

        Arrays.sort(mainArr, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] entry1, String[] entry2) {
                if (entry1[0].equals(entry2[0])) {
                    return entry1[1].compareTo(entry2[1]);
                }
                return entry1[0].compareTo(entry2[0]);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mainArr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(mainArr[i][0] + ", " + mainArr[i][1]);
        }
    }
```